# Before the war, how many races were there?

Tags: no-game-no-life

We know that now, after the war is over and the rules have been made, there are 16 Exceeds, including Imanity.

How many were there before that? Has it ever been mentioned?

Comment: I haven't read the whole thing, but I doubt it is ever mentioned, since it is irrelevant to the current storyline.

Comment: I guess, we may get the answer in new series No game No life Zero, which will get release in july 2017